# Google-Charts won't show in WebView (Android 4.0.4)

Tags: android, android-webview, google-visualization, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I've encountered a problem with Google-Charts in the WebView on Android 4.0.4

I've got a little page with a Google-Chart on it, so if I display this html-page in the browser the chart shows up just fine.
If I start my App on the Samsung Galaxy 7 (Android 2.2) the Google-Chart shows up just fine in the WebView too.
But if I start the same App on the Samsung Galaxy 10.1 (Android 4.0.4) the WebView with the Google-Chart is just empty, no error-message or something else, that might be usefull for debugging.

Essentially I just try to load the Google-Chart URL into the WebView:

```java
String url = <google-chart-url>;

// is there something strange with the content?
showContent(url);
WebView webview = ((WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview));
webview.loadUrl(url);
```

Little HTTP-Request to verify that the data from the server is okay:

```java
private void showContent(String url) {

    int TIMEOUT_CONNECTION = 60000;
    int TIMEOUT_SOCKET = 60000;

    // Parameter setzen
    HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, TIMEOUT_CONNECTION);
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, TIMEOUT_SOCKET);

    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
    // Daten holen
    HttpGet getMethod = new HttpGet(url);
    HttpResponse response;
    String raw = new String();

    try {
        response = httpClient.execute(getMethod);

        HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();
        if(responseEntity != null) {
            raw = EntityUtils.toString(responseEntity);
        }

        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "showContent: " + raw);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
    }
}
```

I also tried different WebView settings:

```java
WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
// JavaScriptInterface to handle clicks in the WebView
webview.addJavascriptInterface(new HtmlClick(), "clicks");

webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
```

Is there anyone who encountered a similiar problem or does someone have suggestions what is actually bugged?

Thanks in advance ;)

#### Update:

The Browser on the Samsung Galaxy 10.1 also dosen't display the chart; tested with:

- Internet
- Chrome
- Firefox
- Opera

Comment: is there nobody else who experienced the same problem?